# Got RuntimeException error while composer updating

Tags: laravel, runtimeexception

> [RuntimeException]
>     Could not delete /var/www/music/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/tests/fixtures/specialchars.env:

I got Above error while update the composer.phar update.What will be the solution of this?

Comment: Sounds like a matter of permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide correct permissions and owners to your project and storage folders with `chmod` and `chown`.

Comment: I have done `sudo chown <username>:<group> -R www` according to you and it works perfect. thanks